# Swift get data from Firestore database error timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to get data from firestore database but sometimes created_at is nil it will crash app
for another such as String type, I can set it to empty but for timestamp, I don't know how I can handle it with any help please thanks!

```
       COLLECTION_TM_TRANSITIONS_UAT
            .whereField("sender_name", isEqualTo: username)
//            .order(by: "created_at", descending: true)
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            if error == nil {
                guard let value = documentSnapshot?.documents else { return }
           
                self.tmTransitions  += value.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> TmTransition in
                    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                    let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                    let is_sender = data["is_sender"] as? Bool ?? false
                    let point = data["point"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let username = data["username"] as? String ?? ""
                    let sender_id = data["sender_id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let receiver_id = data["receiver_id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let created_at = data["created_at"] as? Timestamp
                    let sender_name = data["sender_name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let receiver_name = data["receiver_name"] as? String ?? ""
//                    print("sender_name : \(sender_name)")
//                    print("created_at : \(created_at)")
//
//
//                    let date: Date = created_at!.dateValue()
//                    formatter2.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
                   
//                 let createdDate = formatter2.string(from: date)
                    return TmTransition(id: queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID, sender_id: sender_id, receiver_id: receiver_id, username: username, is_sender: is_sender, point: point, email: email,created_at: created_at,sender_name: sender_name,receiver_name: receiver_name)
              
                }
               
            }
```

Comment: What is the crash error that happens? You have it set as an optional, so it's hard to tell what the crash would be. And then sometimes it's a String? In what format? It would probably be good to provide a sample of your data so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: it's crush because I tried to unwrap optional value from timestamp to string type but actually, timestamp is nil you can see in my model here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rJIR96benvYb8InvSmQHyYReXME4X4C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, yes, if you use `!` to unwrap a `nil` optional, it will crash. Again, without a sample of what the data looks like, this is going to be pretty tough to diagnose. Also, if you have the option, normalizing your data so that `created_at` is *one* type would make your life *much* easier.

Comment: There are some good comments here about safely handling optionals but they aren't a solution because we don't know what you want to do IF there is no created_at timestamp. First question is; can you prevent it from being nil in the first place? Second question; if not, what do you want to do if that field doesn't exist? Do you want to supply a default value or stop and ask the user to enter something or....? Please update the question so we can provide a more clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `guard` and use the `datevalue()`:

```
guard let created_at = data["created_at"] as? Timestamp else {
    print("Cannot cast timestamp")
    return
}
// Then use: 
print("Document date: " + created_at.dateValue())
```